# Mandatory fields in hibernate entity

Tags: java, hibernate, reflection

I have a **Person** bean with required **ssn** and **gender** as required fields

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @NotNull
    private String ssn;//This is mandatory
    @NotNull
    private Gender gender;//This is mandatory
    private String firstname;
    private Date dateOfBirth;
    ...
}
```

I'm in a class MandatoryFieldsFinder that don't have access to person Object, is there a way to find out these mandatory fields at runtime in hibernate or using reflection? I'am a complete novice in Reflection and dont want to use it.

```
public class MandatoryFieldsFinder{

    public list getAllMandatoryFieldsFromPerson(){
    ....
    //I need to find the mandatory fields in Person class here
    ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this at runtime, the only way is to use reflection (it's actually quite fun when you get the hang of it!). A simple utility method like the following should do it:

```
/**
 * Gets a List of fields from the class that have the supplied annotation.
 * 
 * @param clazz
 *            the class to inspect
 * @param annotation
 *            the annotation to look for
 * @return the List of fields with the annotation
 */
public static List<Field> getAnnotatedFields(Class<?> clazz,
        Class<? extends Annotation> annotation) {

    List<Field> annotatedFields = new ArrayList<Field>();

    for (Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (field.isAnnotationPresent(annotation)) {
            annotatedFields.add(field);
        }
    }

    return annotatedFields;

}
```

You can then implement your `getAllMandatoryFieldsFromPerson()` method by using:

```
getAnnotatedFields(MyClass.class, NotNull.class)
```

Please note though, that not all annotations are available at runtime - it depends on their [retention policy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html). If `@NotNull` has a retention policy of `RUNTIME`, then it's fine, otherwise you'd have to do something at compile time.

I'd be interested why you need this information in the first place - it's typically something that JSR303 bean validation would take care of for you.

Comment: One reason i need this is to have auto set JS validations on the client side for the required fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can query for annotation presence on a field:

```
  // walk through fields
    for (Field field : extractFields(target)) {

        final InjectView annotation = field.getAnnotation(InjectView.class);
        if (annotation != null) {
```

...  do whatever necessary 
            }
        }

https://github.com/ko5tik/andject/blob/master/src/main/java/de/pribluda/android/andject/ViewInjector.java